# MVC Application running inside the main method

Tags: php, model-view-controller, frameworks

I'm creating a personal MVC Framework and i googled around to see the code of existing ones and take some inspiration. I noticed (but i probably got it wrong), that for example CodeIgniter's Application are somehow included inside a main method. (Noticed because of the use of $this in the application system).

How does it works? Is it recommended (i think that having some background procedures could help me a lot)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter uses a bootstrap file to include and initialise all required dependencies. Most MVC's such as Zend and CI use this bootstrap file. Zend actually has ini files that are used in the bootstrap procedure. You can read more information on the bootstrap by wiki or just google it. If you are writing your own, most MVC's are primarily based on the URI segments with apache mod rewrites (clean urls), where each segment has their own purpose. You use routes in order to direct pages to a different URI structure etc. Such as http://domain.com/controller/method/some/other/segments... So that url would load the "controller" and invoke the "method" in that controller. What would be interesting to do is write a php MVC utilising the namespaces as of 5.3 > ... Do something like namespace controller; to keep things organised and clean. I often have to use some kind of naming convention due to conflicts in class names such as Class Some extends CI_Controller (would be my controller) and Some_Model extends CI_Model (would be my models) etc. Have fun with it!